# Shell function sensitive to both the location of the executable and spaces in path

Tags: windows, shell, vb6

Until recently this VB6 code worked on my windows 7 64 bit machine

```
 Shell "c:\My App\Helpers\Helper.exe"
```

The error message this now throws is

> Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)

Since it stopped working I have found that moving the directory Helpers to the desktop fixes the issue.
So also does getting rid of the space in the path by renaming the

> My App

folder as

> MyApp

So also does inserting opening and closing quotes as in :

```
Shell """c:\My App\Helpers\Helper.exe"""
```

Meanwhile if the Helpers folder is on the desktop I can insert a space into the path by renaming the folder 'Hel pers' and it still works without the extra quotes.

So these all work:

```
Shell """c:\My App\Helpers\Helper.exe"""
Shell "c:\Users\UserA\Desktop\Helpers\Helper.exe"
Shell "c:\Users\UserA\Desktop\Hel pers\Helper.exe"
```

while the original no longer works though it did for years

```
Shell "c:\My App\Helpers\Helper.exe"
```

What could be the cause of this, and is there a way to restore the behaviour to the way it was before?

Comment: Any chance there's a file or directory `C:\My` ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I thought that you might be onto something there for a moment but no unfortunately.

Comment: Why not just put the quotes in? `Shell """c:\My App\Helpers\Helper.exe"""` That looks much more correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

The Shell() function dated from much simpler times, it is ambiguous today.  The command can also mean "start the `c:\My` program and pass it the `App\Helpers.Helper.exe` command line argument".

Why it triggers on your machine is impossible to tell from a distance, especially when you obfuscate the real name of the program.  An infamous example is having a file or directory named `Program` in the root directory.  Now c:\Program Files\Etcetera no longer works.

Using the double-quotes is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ShellExecute() API instead of Shell()

```
Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
               (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpszOp As String, _
                ByVal lpszFile As String, ByVal lpszParams As String, _
                ByVal LpszDir As String, ByVal FsShowCmd As Long) _
                As Long
```

For more info : [example on microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170918)

[EDIT]

A small example with only the parts that you (probably) need:

```
'1 Form with:
'  1 Command button: Name="Command1"
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpszOp As String, ByVal lpszFile As String, ByVal lpszParams As String, ByVal lpszDir As String, ByVal FsShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim strPath As String
  Dim strExe As String
  Dim lngReturn As Long
  strExe = "TestProg.exe"
  strPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ShellTest"
  lngReturn = ShellExecute(0, "Open", strExe, vbNullString, strPath, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
  Caption = CStr(Now) & " : " & CStr(lngReturn)
End Sub
```

When you click on the command button it will execute TextProg.exe from the ShellTest directory

In the caption of the form it will show the return value of the ShellExecute command

Comment: Seems a lot more complicated with all those parameters, is it immune from problems with spaces in the path?

Comment: I created a test project which worked including spaces in the name. See my edit for the project, so you can run it yourself ... I tested it on Windows 7, 64 bit